# SqlStageExecution Error in executing Presto query

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I am trying to run Presto on Amazon.
I have just one node on which I configured Presto server. I haven't setup Presto on other nodes in cluster yet. Trying out a simple select query throws the following exception.
Any insights. is it coming because Presto is configured (coordinator) on just one node.
Error is below

```
com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution Error while starting stage 20131113_180914_00005_b2tyu.1

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Response is null.; Host Details : local host is: "ip-10-248-27-187.us-east-2.compute.internal/10.248.27.187"; destination host is: "ip-10-248-27-187.us-east-2.compute.internal":9000;

        at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160) ~[guava-15.0.jar:na]

        at com.facebook.presto.hive.HiveSplitIterable$HiveSplitQueue.computeNext(HiveSplitIterable.java:433) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are encountering is the same problem that was reported on the presto-users Google Group.  According to Dain's response, the issue is that the current Presto code is designed to work with "code includes Cloudera Hadoop version 2.0.0-cdh4.3.0".   If you are using Amazon Elastic MapReduce, you may be running into an incompatibility between Hadoop 2.2.0 and the specific version of Hadoop that Presto is currently integrated with.

Here'a a link to the related discussion on the presto-users Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/presto-users/lVLvMGP1sKE

Comment: thanks. Thats helpful thread. Did anyone try Presto with HBase, I am assuming it is not going to work given there is no connector.